# How can I create a list whose items can be dragged and dropped onto one another to create groups within the list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Let's say I have a list containing many items. As the user I want to drag an item and drop it onto another item so that I can logically group those two items into a nested list, or an entirely new list separate from the main source list.

When a group would get created or updated it would need to update the database to reflect the changes.

Is there a jQuery plugin or other preexisting solution which would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the draggable jQuery UI function...
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Thanks, but I have taken a look at it and still not sure how to achieve what I want.

Comment: I'm talking about one list, and the ability to somehow group its items by drag-and-drop. As an example, imagine a list of 30 items each with a unique label and a grey background. You can drag any item onto any other in the list and as soon as you drop it it changes its position in the list to be under the one you dropped onto and both of their backgrounds change to red (or some other shared color) to communicate the idea of those two items belonging to a group within that list of 30 items. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need for a plug in, jQuery itself can do it, you can use jQueryUI. I suggest "[Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#accepted-elements)" (Together of course with the Draggable)